# OnCollisionExit() Not Working on my script unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Am Working With Unity 3d and know little scripting and unity well. I Came To a point where I don't know what to do. My OnCollisionExit Don't Work on collision exit there is moment = true this dont work. Somebody told me you have not reset the variable. So I Don't Know How To Make It So Please Help. Thanks In Advance
This is The Player Script This Is My Script or code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public Transform housepos;
    public Transform deadpos;
    public static bool safe1_click = false;
    public bool safe1_clicked = false;
    public float speed = 25;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    Collider mycollider;
    float Walk = 8;
    float jump = 7;
    float sadWalk = 6;
    float idle = 0;
    public static bool stopwalking = false;
    public static bool Jump = false;
    public static bool sadwalk = false;
    public static bool freeze = false;
    public static bool yourchance = false;
    public static bool movement = true;
    public bool movement23 = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        mycollider = transform.GetComponent<Collider>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        anim.SetFloat("Animation", Walk);
        stopwalking = false;
        Jump = false;
        freeze = false;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement23 = movement;
        if (movement == true)
        {
            safe1_click = safe1_clicked;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        }
       
        if (Jump == true)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Animation", jump);
        }
        if (Jump == true)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Animation", sadWalk);
        }
        if (stopwalking == true)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Animation", idle);
        }
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "stop")
        {
            Debug.Log("Stopped");
            spawner.stopspawn = true;
            movement = false;
            return;
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "dec")
        {
            Debug.Log("oh");
            freeze = true;
        }

    }
    public void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "stop")
        {
            Debug.Log("Spawning");
            spawner.stopspawn = false;
            movement = true;
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "dec")
        {
            Debug.Log("oh");
            freeze = false;
           
        }

    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "fre")
        {
            spawner.yourchance = true;
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "dec")
        {
            freeze = true;
            Debug.Log("oh");
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "new")
        {
            yourchance = true;
            Debug.Log("stopstop");
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "con")
        {
            Debug.Log("collide happened");
            movement = true;
        }

    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "dec")
        {
            freeze = false;
            Debug.Log("oh");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens? If neither Debug.Log is being triggered, have you checked that the gameobjects have these tags assigned? Are you sure that neither colliding body has a trigger collider and that this player has a rigidbody?

Comment: movement = true.on the first of tag stop

Comment: Are you sure your tags are correct? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @yuvi-raj, One tip: Don't use == operator for comparing tags. Use CompareTag(tagname) method (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("stop")) to compare tags. If the tag is not defined, it will throw an exception but == operator will simply return false.

Comment: That Dont work sir